# How to export json data to excel as a date using alasql?

Tags: excel, angular8, alasql

I'm using alasql to export a data to excel using angular 8 and alasql 0.6.2. It is working perfectly fine. Code snippet below -

> const opts = [{ sheetid: 'Sheet 1', header: true }, { sheetid: 'Sheet 2', header: false }];

> const fileName = 'Test.xlsx';

> const res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("' + fileName + '",?) FROM ?', [opts, [data1, data2]]);

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZicwC.png)

But the data in the json above (data1['birthDay'] = '14 September 2020') has some date variables which on export I could not format as a date in excel. How will I change the format of the date column during export ?